# Subquery returns more than one row and stops working

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have a table which has got a column. I have to fetch the values from the column and modify it in the view before comparing it with an externally supplied value.

For that I am using the following query:

```
 SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM tblMaster WITH (NOLOCK)
 WHERE (SELECT test 
        FROM
            (SELECT RIGHT('00000000000000000' + RTRIM(CODE), 17) as test 
             FROM tblMaster ) t) = '00001231231231231'
```

Subquery returns modified values of the column extracted from the actual table in form of a column. So I am using the column returned out of the subquery. I don't know if I can use a subquery which returns a column on the left side of equality.

Subquery returns multiple values.

Comment: I don't get what you want to do. Your WHERE-condition is exactly the same as `WHERE right('00000000000000000'+RTRIM(CODE),17) = '00001231231231231'`. And this should be the same as `WHERE CODE= '1231231231231'`

Comment: As dnoeth said, there's no need to prepend your value with 0s. These are implicitly trimmed off when the SQL engine compares the integers.

Comment: I notice the NOLOCK hint. You might want to take a look at this before you develop the habit of littering your database with this hint. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a subquery for this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM tblMaster WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE right('00000000000000000' + RTRIM(CODE), 17) = '00001231231231231';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this. You don't need to add 0s to integers, SQL will trim them off when comparing. Also you don't need the subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM tblMaster WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE CODE = '1231231231231'
```